# Disable past dates in datepicker-popup

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have below code snippet in which datepicker control is there.

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" class="form-control  input-sm" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="startDate" required />
```

Here, i have to disable the past dates in the datepicker control and below is what i have configured but its not working. Am I missing something here?

```
App.config(['datepickerConfig', 'datepickerPopupConfig', function (datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig) {
    datepickerConfig.startingDay = 1;
    datepickerConfig.showWeeks = true;

    datepickerPopupConfig.datepickerPopup = "dd-MMMM-yyyy";
    datepickerPopupConfig.currentText = "Now";
    datepickerPopupConfig.clearText = "Erase";
    datepickerPopupConfig.closeText = "Close";
}]);
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that tells the date picker to disable past dates. Why do you think this should disable past dates? Read http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.4/#/datepicker, and use the **appropriate** option.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to narrow the range of possible dates add `min-date` or `max-date` [just as in the example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QiQDiPXhuO0eTPxxdGnd?p=preview).

Here's the relevant [part of documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker):

> - max-date (Default: null) - Defines the maximum available date.
> - min-date (Default: null) - Defines the minimum available date.

Answer (score 3):

Since angular ui-bootstrap version 1.1.0 you need to use an attribute called *datepicker-options* to configure a datepicker:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-options="dateOptions" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" is-open="popup.opened"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

Now you only need to set the minDate property to the current date or any other date you like to be the minimum Date of the datepicker. Instead of writing the datepicker configuration in the .config block of your application, you should write it in a controller or a service:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
   minDate: new Date() 
};

$scope.popup = {
   opened: false
};

$scope.open = function() {
   $scope.popup.opened = true;
};
```

For more information, please read the [official documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).