# How to disable the past date in datepicker angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I had a input field with datepicker..I need the user to select date only from the present date and past dates should not be clickable..Below is the code.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
 <input  class="form-control" type="datetime" date-time auto-close="true" view="date" 
  min-view="date" maxlength="10" format="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="$ctrl.DateInput" 
  placeholder="renewal date" required="true">
</div>
```

Quick help appreciated..
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what datepicker you're using, but is there a min-date option?

Comment: looks like you are using HTML5 datetime use min="<date>" but see for browser support http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: see this demo link http://plnkr.co/edit/W5pb1boMLOHZFnWkMU8o?p=preview

Comment: try with setting min="your min date value"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693771/disable-past-dates-in-datepicker-popup

Comment: min date should be current date

Answer (score 6):

```
   <input class="form-control m-input pl-6" type="date" 
   [min]="todayDate"formControlName="dateValidity">
```

The min and max are the date properties which used to validate the input range and these properties will disable before and after dates on the calendar popup.

in your ts define min date

```
     todayDate=this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Why you've used formControlName="dateValidity" in the input element? If I write the same in my input element I get an error in the browser console.

Answer (score 5):

### Code:

```html
<html>
<head>    
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="Padding:20px;">
    <form>
    
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
    Date: 
        <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}" min-date="mindate" ng-model="dt" is-open="showdp" />
        <span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showcalendar($event)">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
        angular.module('myApp').controller('myCntrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.today = function () {
                $scope.dt = new Date();
            };
            $scope.mindate = new Date();
            $scope.dateformat="MM/dd/yyyy";
            $scope.today();
            $scope.showcalendar = function ($event) {
                $scope.showdp = true;
            };
            $scope.showdp = false;
        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Wokrs as:

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to narrow the range of possible dates add min-date or max-date just as in the example. 
`http://plnkr.co/edit/QiQDiPXhuO0eTPxxdGnd?p=preview`

Here's the relevant part of documentation:

```
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker
```

max-date (Default: null) - Defines the maximum available date.
min-date (Default: null) - Defines the minimum available date.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable past dates in an HTML 5 input of type datetime-local in Angular by using a combination of HTML and TypeScript.

**component.html**

```
<input type="datetime-local" min="{{dateToday() | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sss'}}" />
```

We are using the min attribute to set the minimum allowed date to the current date and time. The `minDate()` function returns the current date and time in a format that is compatible with the `datetime-local` input type. You can modify this to match your needs.

**component.ts**

```
dateToday(): Date {
  const now = new Date();
  const year = now.getFullYear();
  const month = now.getMonth() + 1;
  const day = now.getDate();
  const hour = now.getHours();
  const minute = now.getMinutes();
  return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);
}
```

This function returns a `Date` object representing the current date and time, but with the seconds and milliseconds set to zero. This ensures that the minimum date is the beginning of the current minute, rather than the exact moment the user loads the page.

The `datetime-local` input will only allow the user to select dates and times that are in the future, starting from the current day.

I hope this proves helpful for any new visitors to this post.

Answer (score 0):

in your ts file just add:

```js
minDate = new Date();
```

in Angular 16, import `MatInputModule`

in HTML, just add this in input:

```
[min]="minDate"
```

```
<div class="tagus-form-group without-icon">
       <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
             <mat-label>End date</mat-label>
                 <input [min]="minDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="endDatePicker" formControlName="endDate" />
             <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>    
             <mat-datepicker #endDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
       </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: You mention version 16 but the question is tagged "angularjs" wich means 1.x.